# Github actions docker build "uses" vs manual

Tags: docker, github-actions

tonight I stumbled across something I found really strange and I can't find a good answer to it. I'm building a docker image on my Raspberry Pi (where this is a dashboard acting as a home server). I'm still fairly new to using Github actions, but I use a Gitlab/Jenkins setup at work.

With the exact same code, building and pushing the docker image with the following took around 10 minutes. I ran into some further issues and it timed out, so I thought of building it manually as opposed to the "uses: docker/build-push-action" method.

I'm struggling to understand what's happening under the hood and why there is such a massive performance difference. Is there a reason why the "using" method might be preferred?

Raspberry Pi B3+, Ubuntu arm64

~10 Minutes. Sample run: https://github.com/helblingjoel/piserver/actions/runs/2332932188

```yaml
      - name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v1
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_PASSWORD }}

      - name: Set up Docker Buildx
        id: buildx
        uses: docker/setup-buildx-action@v2

      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v2
        with:
          push: true
          tags: helblingjoel/piserver:${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}
          cache-from: type=registry,ref=helblingjoel/piserver:buildcache
          cache-to: type=registry,ref=helblingjoel/piserver:buildcache,mode=max
```

~3 minutes. Sample run: https://github.com/helblingjoel/piserver/actions/runs/2334507767

```yaml
      - name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKER_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.

      - name: Build docker image
        run: docker build -t helblingjoel/piserver:${{ steps.date.outputs.date }} .

      - name: Push docker image
        run: docker push helblingjoel/piserver:${{ steps.date.outputs.date }}
```

The Dockerfile used for those was identical.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Which of the steps is taking up the additional time? Have you turned on debugging? https://docs.github.com/en/actions/monitoring-and-troubleshooting-workflows/enabling-debug-logging

Comment: The `docker/build-push-action` uses [buildx](https://github.com/docker/buildx) -- are you aware of that?

Comment: @EdwardThomson Building the docker image is taking much longer - particularly npm install. I haven't turned it on as it appears to just run slower

Comment: @rethab I can see that it's using buildx, but as I'm not asking it to build on another platform I wouldn't have thought it would be emulating anything.
Other than multiarch support, is there a good reason to use buildx over just native docker?